# Is this assembler bug? bound instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, att, objdump

About bytepattern `622c24`, there are 2 kind of case. 



The first case : `objdump` - `as` pair.

1. `objdump` disassembles `622c24` to : **`bound  %ebp,(%esp)`**
2. linux `as` assembles `bound  %ebp,(%esp)` to : `622c24`

The second case : library `Capstone`- `keystone` pair.

1. `Capstone` disassembles `622c24` to :  **`bound (%esp), %ebp`**
2. `Keystone` assembles `bound (%esp), %ebp` to : `622c24`

As you can see above, the position of source and destination is reversed.

- objdump  : **`bound  %ebp,(%esp)`**
- Capstone :   **`bound (%esp), %ebp`**

According to AT&T syntax, `BOUND r32, m32` is correct.
Therefore, that means Capstone-keystone pare is the correct one.

***Q. So,  `objdump`-`as` has problem on disassembling `bound` instruction?***
***Is it a bug of binutils?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is probably a design bug in AT&T syntax.  They normally follow the pattern of reversing the operands from Intel-syntax, and renaming the sign/zero-extension mnemonics (`cdq` => `cltq`, `movsx eax, byte[mem]` => `movsbl`).  Deviations from that can be considered design bugs.

But not implementation bugs unless older versions were different.  It's valid (but unpleasant) when AT&T just does whatever it wants and makes up its own rules for different instructions.  This might be another case of compat with the original Unixware assembler. (see below).

---

**[The `bound` instruction](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BOUND.html) doesn't write either of its input operands**, so neither one is really a destination.  And unlike `cmp`, operand order doesn't have any meaning.  It just checks the register against both upper/lower bounds, and raises a `#BR` exception if it's out of bounds.

There's only one opcode for it, and it requires register + memory operands (in the ModR/M `r` and `r/m` fields.

---

`objdump -d` lists the register operand first in both AT&T and Intel syntax.

I assembled `db 0x62, 0x2c, 0x24` with NASM and linked it with `ld -melf_i386` into a 32-bit ELF executable (because I have a wrapper script that makes it easier to assemble+link+disassemble than to *just* assemble).

```
   objdump -drwC -Mintel
8048060:       62 2c 24                bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [esp]

   objdump -drwC -Matt
8048060:       62 2c 24                bound  %ebp,(%esp)
```

---

**It does seem to be a quirk of AT&T syntax as implemented in binutils** (`as` / `objdump` / `gdb`) that `bound` *requires* the register arg to be listed first.

```
bound  %eax, (%edx)  # assembles fine
bound (%edx), %eax   # foo.s:2: Error: operand size mismatch for `bound'
```

I assume it's the same in Intel-syntax mode that it requires the register arg to be first.  There's no ambiguity in meaning here, just an odd design choice to not reverse the operands vs. Intel syntax.

---

**Related: [AT&T syntax also has "bugs" according to the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.30/as/i386_002dBugs.html):**

> 9.15.16 AT&T Syntax bugs
>
> The UnixWare assembler, and probably other AT&T derived ix86 Unix assemblers, generate floating point instructions with reversed source and destination registers in certain cases. Unfortunately, gcc and possibly many other programs use this reversed syntax, so we’re stuck with it.
>
> For example
>
> ```
>    fsub %st,%st(3)
> ```
>
> results in `%st(3)` being updated to `%st - %st(3)` rather than the expected `%st(3) - %st`. This happens with all the non-commutative arithmetic floating point operations with two register operands where the source register is `%st` and the destination register is `%st(i)`.

So AT&T syntax has actual bugs where both orders are valid and mean *different* things.  I think we can group this operand "reversal" in with that.

---

`ndisasm -b32` disassembles it as `622C24  bound ebp,[esp]`, matching the Intel manual's operand order.

Comment: If you pull out the original iapx186/188 manual Intel designated the register as the destination operand and the memory address where the two bounds are as the source. The manual also shows coding examples. The way I see it, anything that diverged from the original manuals for these processors is likely a bug. Just my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Is it significantly different from http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BOUND.html?  The current manual definitely lists it as `BOUND r32, m32&32`  (or 16), but doesn't refer to any of the operands as source or destination, and the OPERATION section doesn't write memory or registers.  Anyway, AT&T syntax is free to make up whatever they want.  The less they stick to "intel-with-reversed-operands" the less useful / easy-to-learn it is, but Intel's manuals do not have the final say in AT&T syntax design.  But yeah, I'm fine with calling it an AT&T syntax bug.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: updated with a new section to say that we can consider this a syntax design bug.